# MongoDB: How to implement a PUT method for saving Objects?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+-+Saving+Objects+Using+DBObject

This page is about saving and retrieving objects in MongoDB. But after implementing DBObject, I have to override a bunch of methods. Does anyone know how to implement a PUT method so that "myTweet.put("user", userId);" can work?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of implementing [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBObject.html) just extend [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html)

```
class Tweet extends BasicDBObject {
  public Tweet() {
    super();
  }
  public Tweet(BasicDBObject base) {
    super();
    this.putAll(base);
  }
}

Tweet myTweet = new Tweet();
myTweet.put("user", userId);
```

[BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) implements [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBObject.html) so a class that extends it can be passed to any function that expects a class that implements `DBObject`.  If you wanted to implement the interface you would have to supply some container class to store the tweet attributes BasicDBObject does this by extending another class called `BasicBSONObject` which you can see in the [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.java), a naive implementation would look like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.bson.BSONObject;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;


public class Tweet implements DBObject {
    private Map<String, Object> data;
    private boolean partial;

    public Tweet() {
        data = new HashMap<>();
        partial = false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        return data.put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void putAll(BSONObject o) {
        data.putAll(o.toMap());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void putAll(Map m) {
        data.putAll(m);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Map toMap() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public Object removeField(String key) {
        return data.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(String key) {
        return data.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsField(String key) {
        return data.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return data.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public void markAsPartialObject() {
        partial = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPartialObject() {
        return partial;
    }
}
```

This class implements the `DBObject` and uses a `HashMap` to store it's properties.

Comment: However, I extending from BasicDBObject, you will not be able to do:

Tweet myTweet = (Tweet)collection.findOne();

Comment: The answer does not address his question of how to implement the interface

Comment: Added a simple implementation.